# Python and CSV; how to truncate all values in a column?

Tags: python, regex, csv

Given a simple CSV file like this:

```
Django,Gunslinger,101-707
KingSchultz,Dentist,205-707
Tatum,Marshall,615-707
Broomhilda,Wife,910-707
...,...,...
```

How do you truncate all the values in the last column so that only the first three digits remain?  (unrelated:  so they can be used in math operations)

Desired CSV:

```
Django,Gunslinger,101
KingSchultz,Dentist,205
Tatum,Marshall,615
Broomhilda,Wife,910
...,...,...
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
import csv
import re
r = csv.reader(open(input.csv))
for row in r:
    re.sub('\-.*', '', row[3])
writer = csv.writer(open('output.csv', 'w'))
writer.writerow(row)
```

I've verified the `regex` in `re.sub` works correctly.  Have tried dozens of variations, many hours searching, but cannot get the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using `re` module,

```
import csv

r = csv.reader(open("sample.csv", "rb"))
writer = csv.writer(open("output.csv", "wb"))

for row in r:
    row[2] = row[2][:3]
    writer.writerow(row)
```

As @TigerRedMike pointed out in Python 3.X, instead of `'rb'` and `'wb'`, `'r'` and `'w'` should be used respectively to read and write the files.

Comment: Tested working on Python 2.7.6 and 3.4.3.  Thank you @praba230890.  I edited the answer to include a simple error that may confuse someone else on Python 3.4.3.

Comment: Can you explain the syntax of `[:3]`?

Comment: It's string slicing, [:3] slices the first 3 chars of a string and returns it. Check this out https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings

Answer (score 0):

`re.sub` returns the string with the substitution. it does not affect the third argument itself

Answer (score 0):

First thing is `re.sub` returns a new value, it doesn't replace the value in the row.

secondly, `row` is a running variable, you should handle this within the loop.

Here your code modified to work correctly (for python3):

```
import csv
import re
r = csv.reader(open('.../test.csv'))
with open('.../test2.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in r:
        row[2] = re.sub('\-.*', '', row[2])
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Tested working on Python 2.7.6 and 3.4.3. Thank you @DomTomCat.  Since this answer uses regular expressions, it will work on complex edits.

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil -- DonaldKnuth] (http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
import re

r = csv.reader(open('input.csv'))
writer = csv.writer(open('/tmp/output.csv', 'w'))

for row in r:
    tmp = re.sub('\-.*', '', row)
    writer.writerow(tmp)
```